# Windows 10 Black Screen on login - Explorer.EXE is crashing

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

## Problem

On logging in to Windows 10 after update, there is a black screen.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> opens the task manager.

## Research

From the Task Manager, we are able to run the Event Viewer thru File > Run > `eventvwr`.

The Event Viewer's Windows Logs show the following Application Error:

```
Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, VERSON 10.0.10586
Faulting module name: SHELL32.dll, version 10.0.10586.11
Exception code: 0x00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0014693e
Faulting process id: 0x1594
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
```

Also within the Task Manager > Process panel, Windows Explorer does not show as a running Process in the Task Manager.

We have tried to start Windows Explorer thru File > Run > `explorer.exe`.This does not fix the problem, though Windows Explorer **does** show in the Process panel of the Task Manager.

We have tried [restarting in Safe Mode](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2304-safe-mode-start-windows-10-a.html) thru File > Run > `msconfig` > Boot > Safe Boot. This does allow Explorer to start.

Comment: Does this behavior if you boot into safe mode?  Based on the error, Windows Explorer is crashing, that indicates something is causing it to crash.

Comment: I will try to boot in safe mode.

Comment: @Ramhound Safe mode lets Explorer open. Hmm. Now what?

Comment: Determine which process that is automatically starting in normal boot configuration is causing Windows Explorer to crash.  You can accomplish that by using a program like [`Autoruns`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), and force nothing but the bare essentials to launch, then work backwards until you find the culprit.

Comment: Found it :) It was the OpenOffice QuickStart at `C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3\program\quickstart`. https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/Using_the_Quickstarter_under_Windows

Comment: Why are you putting the solution into the question itself?  You should submit an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32374/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 1):

I had added a desktop background image as my upgrade from Win7 had removed my old one. That seems to have caused the crash described (Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, Faulting module name: SHELL32.dll) for my specific user. Removing the background image in safe mode (e.g. via a visibility enhancement for the visually impaired) cured that crash, setting a standard Microsoft image later caused the same problem again. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Task Manager > Startup panel to disable the startup program that was causing Explorer to crash. In our case, this was the OpenOffice Quickstart.